# rabbitmqctl list_users not working

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, rabbitmqctl

I was getting 104 connection reset by user in my django celery ,I'm assuming it has something to do with guest user, so to check when I did sudo rabbitmqctl list_users on my server, it just waits forever and does nothing. If anyone knows about both let me know. Also if you could share some rabbitmq pointers then it would be great.

Comment: Did you check the rabbitmq logs?

Comment: yes not much helpful.. I guess it was saying that it wasn't able to connect guest user.